# Is there a way to use TsLint without installing Node or WebEssentials?

Tags: typescript, web-essentials

Is it possible to use TsLint without installing Node and/or Web Essentials? I just want something small and light I can run on the windows command line, like with JsHint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But if you have node installed you can run ttslint from the common line. Just do ""npm install tslint -g"

See https://www.npmjs.org/package/tslint

Comment: I was having problems getting it to run with a fresh Node install. Turns out Node doesn't set the path on Windows until after you logout/in.

Comment: @user826840 it does. Just restart the shell (cmd). Shell doesn't pickup the system path changes untill a restart > at least that has been my experience :)